# cast list of strings as int list in sql query / stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this stored procedure:

```
exec SearchResume @KeywordSearch=N'', @GreaterThanDate='2013-09-22 00:00:00', 
@CityIDs=N'0,56,31,271,117,327,3,328,228',
@ProvinceIDs=N'0,1,12,13', 
@CountryIDs=N'1', 
@IndustryIDs=N'0,2,3,4,38,113,114,115,116,117'
```

Which doesn't return any results because the ids are in nvarchar but the actual values are integer.

Now, when I test the actual SP with a manual list of int values I'm able to get the results, this is the example:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        UserID,
        ResumeID,
        CASE  a.Confidential WHEN 1 THEN 'Confidential' ELSE LastName + ',' + FirstName END as 'Name',
        a.Description 'ResumeTitle',
        CurrentTitle,
        ModifiedDate,
        CASE ISNULL(b.SalaryRangeID, '0') WHEN '0' THEN CAST(SalarySpecific as nvarchar(8)) ELSE c.Description END 'Salary',
        h.Description 'Relocate',
        i.Description + '-' + j.Description + '-' + k.Description 'Location'
    FROM dbo.Resume a JOIN dbo.Candidate b ON a.CandidateID = b.CandidateID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SalaryRange c ON b.SalaryRangeID = c.SalaryRangeID
    JOIN EducationLevel e ON b.EducationLevelID = e.EducationLevelID
    JOIN CareerLevel f ON b.CareerLevelID = f.CareerLevelID
    JOIN JobType g ON b.JobTypeID = g.JobTypeID
    JOIN WillingToRelocate h ON b.WillingToRelocateID = h.WillingToRelocateID
    JOIN City i ON b.CityID = i.CityID
    JOIN StateProvince j ON j.StateProvinceID = b.StateProvinceID
    JOIN Country k ON k.CountryID = b.CountryID
    WHERE (b.CityID IN (0,56,31,125,229,5,219,8,228))
    AND (b.StateProvinceID IN (0,1,13))
    AND (b.CountryID IN (1))
    AND (b.IndustryPreferenceID IN (0,2,3,4,5,6,115,116,117))
```

I would like to know what can I do to send a list of int values, not a list of nvarchar values since as you can see the query doesn't work properly.

### Update

Original SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchResume]
     @KeywordSearch nvarchar(500),
     @GreaterThanDate datetime,
     @CityIDs nvarchar(500),
     @ProvinceIDs nvarchar(500),
     @CountryIDs nvarchar(500),
     @IndustryIDs nvarchar(500)
    
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT
                UserID,
                ResumeID,
                CASE  a.Confidential WHEN 1 THEN ''Confidential'' ELSE LastName + '','' + FirstName END as ''Name'',
                a.Description ''ResumeTitle'',
                CurrentTitle,
                ModifiedDate,
                CurrentEmployerName,
                PersonalDescription,
                CareerObjectives,
                CASE ISNULL(b.SalaryRangeID, ''0'') WHEN ''0'' THEN CAST(SalarySpecific as nvarchar(8)) ELSE c.Description END ''Salary'',
                e.Description ''EducationLevel'',
                f.Description ''CareerLevel'',
                g.Description ''JobType'',
                h.Description ''Relocate'',
                i.Description + ''-'' + j.Description + ''-'' + k.Description ''Location''
            FROM dbo.Resume a JOIN dbo.Candidate b ON a.CandidateID = b.CandidateID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SalaryRange c ON b.SalaryRangeID = c.SalaryRangeID
            JOIN EducationLevel e ON b.EducationLevelID = e.EducationLevelID
            JOIN CareerLevel f ON b.CareerLevelID = f.CareerLevelID
            JOIN JobType g ON b.JobTypeID = g.JobTypeID
            JOIN WillingToRelocate h ON b.WillingToRelocateID = h.WillingToRelocateID
            JOIN City i ON b.CityID = i.CityID
            JOIN StateProvince j ON j.StateProvinceID = b.StateProvinceID
            JOIN Country k ON k.CountryID = b.CountryID
            WHERE ( (ModifiedDate > ''' + CAST(@GreaterThanDate as nvarchar(55)) + ''')
                
            
                    '
IF (LEN(@CityIDs) >0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + 'AND (b.CityID IN (' + @CityIDs + '))'
END
IF (LEN(@ProvinceIDs) >0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + 'AND (b.StateProvinceID IN (' + @ProvinceIDs + '))'
END
IF (LEN(@CountryIDs) >0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + 'AND (b.CountryID IN (' + @CountryIDs + '))'
END
IF (LEN(@IndustryIDs) >0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + 'AND (b.IndustryPreferenceID IN (' + @IndustryIDs + '))'
END
        
IF (LEN(@KeywordSearch) > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + ' AND (' + @KeywordSearch + ')'
END

SET @sql = @sql + ') ORDER BY ModifiedDate desc'

--select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql

END
```

Comment: Is dynamic sql an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Table-Valued Function which takes the nVarChar and creates a new record for each value, where you tell it the delimiter.  My example here returns a table with a single Value column, you can then use this as a sub query for your IN Selection :

```
Create  FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitVariable]
(
    @List nvarchar(2000),
    @delimiter nvarchar(5)
)  
RETURNS @RtnValue table 
(

    Id int identity(1,1),
    Variable varchar(15),
    Value nvarchar(100)
) 
AS  
BEGIN
Declare @Count int
set @Count = 1
    While (Charindex(@delimiter,@List)>0)
    Begin 
        Insert Into @RtnValue (Value, Variable)
        Select 
            Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@delimiter,@List)-1))),
        Variable = 'V' + convert(varchar,@Count)
            Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@delimiter,@List)+len(@delimiter),len(@List))
        Set @Count = @Count + 1
    End  

    Insert Into @RtnValue (Value, Variable)
        Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List)), Variable = 'V' + convert(varchar,@Count)

        Return
END
```

Then in your where statement you could do the following:

```
WHERE (b.CityID IN (Select Value from fnSplitVariable(@CityIDs, ','))
```

I have included your original Procedure, and updated it to use the function above:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchResume]
     @KeywordSearch nvarchar(500),
     @GreaterThanDate datetime,
     @CityIDs nvarchar(500),
     @ProvinceIDs nvarchar(500),
     @CountryIDs nvarchar(500),
     @IndustryIDs nvarchar(500)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(4000)

SET @sql = N'
       DECLARE      @KeywordSearch nvarchar(500),
                    @CityIDs nvarchar(500),
                    @ProvinceIDs nvarchar(500),
                    @CountryIDs nvarchar(500),
                    @IndustryIDs nvarchar(500) 

       SET @KeywordSearch = '''+@KeywordSearch+'''
       SET @CityIDs = '''+@CityIDs+'''
       SET @ProvinceIDs = '''+@ProvinceIDs+'''
       SET @CountryIDs = '''+@CountryIDs+'''
       SET @IndustryIDs = '''+@IndustryIDs+'''
SELECT DISTINCT
                UserID,
                ResumeID,
                CASE  a.Confidential WHEN 1 THEN ''Confidential'' ELSE LastName + '','' +      FirstName END as ''Name'',
                a.Description ''ResumeTitle'',
                CurrentTitle,
                ModifiedDate,
                CurrentEmployerName,
                PersonalDescription,
                CareerObjectives,
                CASE ISNULL(b.SalaryRangeID, ''0'') WHEN ''0'' THEN CAST(SalarySpecific as   nvarchar(8)) ELSE c.Description END ''Salary'',
                e.Description ''EducationLevel'',
                f.Description ''CareerLevel'',
                g.Description ''JobType'',
                h.Description ''Relocate'',
                i.Description + ''-'' + j.Description + ''-'' + k.Description ''Location''
            FROM dbo.Resume a JOIN dbo.Candidate b ON a.CandidateID = b.CandidateID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN SalaryRange c ON b.SalaryRangeID = c.SalaryRangeID
            JOIN EducationLevel e ON b.EducationLevelID = e.EducationLevelID
            JOIN CareerLevel f ON b.CareerLevelID = f.CareerLevelID
            JOIN JobType g ON b.JobTypeID = g.JobTypeID
            JOIN WillingToRelocate h ON b.WillingToRelocateID = h.WillingToRelocateID
            JOIN City i ON b.CityID = i.CityID
            JOIN StateProvince j ON j.StateProvinceID = b.StateProvinceID
            JOIN Country k ON k.CountryID = b.CountryID
            WHERE ( (ModifiedDate > ''' + CAST(@GreaterThanDate as nvarchar(55)) + ''')


                    '
IF (LEN(@CityIDs) >0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + N'AND (b.CityID IN (Select Value from fnSplitVariable(@CityIDs,'','')  ))'
END
IF (LEN(@ProvinceIDs) >0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + N'AND (b.StateProvinceID IN (Select Value from    fnSplitVariable(@ProvinceIDs,'','') ))'
END
IF (LEN(@CountryIDs) >0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + N'AND (b.CountryID IN (Select Value from fnSplitVariable(@CountryIDs,'','')    ))'
END
IF (LEN(@IndustryIDs) >0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + N'AND (b.IndustryPreferenceID IN (Select Value from fnSplitVariable(@IndustryIDs,'','') ))'
END

IF (LEN(@KeywordSearch) > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @sql = @sql + N' AND (' + @KeywordSearch + ')'
END

SET @sql = @sql + N') ORDER BY ModifiedDate desc'

--select @sql
exec sp_executesql @sql

END
```

Comment: this is the error I'm getting http://i.gyazo.com/6f4100aa373904a58daeddeb8fb8f484.png

Comment: edited the answer, I am guessing that there may have been an error in your where clause

Comment: now I'm getting this error: http://gyazo.com/85434dc2865e055f8de4d7ac7adc0a3e Thanks

Comment: This is due to the SQL Script being created in the sql and then getting executed seperately so it cannot see the parameters on the stored procedure.

Comment: I have amended the stored procedure for you, this should hopefully give you what you need, but could possibly be done in a better way, although the KeywordSearch had me scratching my head which is why I added the new declarations in the sql variable.

Comment: thanks for your reply but again it doesn't work, although no error is returned. Looking at the profiler I can see that the items are not visible from the function, although when I execute the select from the parse function I'm able to get the results. Can that be the problem? http://i.gyazo.com/b3862f2a1e252f21bc8dfc373105cb4e.png Thx

Comment: The reason for this is that the sp_executesql returns zero for success or another number for an error.  To use the sp_executesql you would need to either specify output parameters.  But it may be more straight forward to post the results to a table and select on that table after executing the query.

Comment: Thanks, one of the problem was that the size of the parameter was set to 500 and it was trimming the values after that thus not getting any results, your answer was solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT DISTINCT
        UserID,
        ResumeID,
        CASE  a.Confidential WHEN 1 THEN ''Confidential'' ELSE LastName + '','' + FirstName END as ''Name'',
        a.Description ''ResumeTitle'',
        CurrentTitle,
        ModifiedDate,
        CASE ISNULL(b.SalaryRangeID, ''0'') WHEN ''0'' THEN CAST(SalarySpecific as nvarchar(8)) ELSE c.Description END ''Salary'',
        h.Description ''Relocate'',
        i.Description + ''-'' + j.Description + ''-'' + k.Description ''Location''
    FROM dbo.Resume a JOIN dbo.Candidate b ON a.CandidateID = b.CandidateID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SalaryRange c ON b.SalaryRangeID = c.SalaryRangeID
    JOIN EducationLevel e ON b.EducationLevelID = e.EducationLevelID
    JOIN CareerLevel f ON b.CareerLevelID = f.CareerLevelID
    JOIN JobType g ON b.JobTypeID = g.JobTypeID
    JOIN WillingToRelocate h ON b.WillingToRelocateID = h.WillingToRelocateID
    JOIN City i ON b.CityID = i.CityID
    JOIN StateProvince j ON j.StateProvinceID = b.StateProvinceID
    JOIN Country k ON k.CountryID = b.CountryID
    WHERE (b.CityID IN (' + @CityIDs + '))
    AND (b.StateProvinceID IN (' + @ProvinceIDs + '))
    AND (b.CountryID IN (' + @CountryIDs + '))
    AND (b.IndustryPreferenceID IN (' + @IndustryIDs + '))'

EXEC @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a split on the id's that are coming in to the store procedure. So consider this split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos) 
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Id' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)
```

Then you could write your where statement like this:

```
WHERE
    EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM dbo.Split(@CityIDs,',') AS city 
               WHERE city.Data=b.CityID)
    AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM dbo.Split(@ProvinceIDs,',') AS Province 
               WHERE Province.Data=b.StateProvinceID)
    AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM dbo.Split(@CountryIDs,',') AS Country 
               WHERE Country.Data=b.CountryID)
    AND EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM dbo.Split(@IndustryIDs,',') AS Industry 
               WHERE Industry.Data=b.IndustryPreferenceID)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please check the updated description, I've added the original SP, can you please let me know how I can utilize the function with the original SP. Thanks a lot